# struts form and hidden field in javascript

Tags: jsp, struts

I have a form, and i do some calculation using java script (date object is just an example here). I need to use that dateVar in my jsp that the form is sumitted to. Can somebody please help me to get the proper implementation and also if there are any working examples of the same?

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>  
<html:html xhtml="true">  
    <head>  
        <script type="text/javascript">     
            var dateVar = new Date();  
            document.write('<input type="text" id="date" name="date" value=' + dateVar + "/>");  
            document.write('<html:text property="dateVar" value="' + dateVar + '" />');  
        </script>  
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <html:form action="/submitForm">  
            <bean:message key="prompt.clientId"/>:  
            <html:text property="clientId" size="16" maxlength="16"/>  
            <BR/>  
            <html:submit property="display">  
                <bean:message key="button.display"/>  
            </html:submit>  
            <html:submit property="displayAll">  
                <bean:message key="button.displayAll"/>  
            </html:submit>  
            <html:cancel>  
                <bean:message key="button.cancel"/>  
            </html:cancel>  
        </html:form>  
     </body>  
</html:html>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a hidden field on the form and set its value at appropriate time(eg if that can be done at form load, do it; or else fire script on form submit if you are dependent on other form values) and set the hidden field with result.

On the next page / action, the value should be accessible in request parameters.

**--EDIT added sample code (its not the exact, but should be enough to derive the final code)**

```
<script>
function submitClick(){
..
form.getElementbyId('hdnTest').value='computed value';
}
</script>

<s:form>
..
<s:hidden name="test" id="hdnTest"/>
<s:button onClick="submitClick"../>
</s:form>
```

Comment: can you give me sample code if possible? I tried using above but it didnt helped :(